# Replace substring in string with range in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, replace

How can I replace a substring of a string given the starting position and the length?

I was hoping for something like this:

```js
var string = "This is a test string";
string.replace(10, 4, "replacement");
```

so that `string` would equal

```js
"this is a replacement string"
```

..but I can't find anything like that.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this:

```
var outstr = instr.substr(0,start)+"replacement"+instr.substr(start+length);
```

You can add it to the string's prototype:

```
String.prototype.splice = function(start,length,replacement) {
    return this.substr(0,start)+replacement+this.substr(start+length);
}
```

(I call this `splice` because it is very similar to the Array function of the same name)

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, this function will replace based on two indices instead of first index and length.

```
splice: function(specimen, start, end, replacement) {
    // string to modify, start index, end index, and what to replace that selection with

    var head = specimen.substring(0,start);
    var body = specimen.substring(start, end + 1); // +1 to include last character
    var tail = specimen.substring(end + 1, specimen.length);

    var result = head + replacement + tail;

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Short RegExp version:

```
str.replace(new RegExp("^(.{" + start + "}).{" + length + "}"), "$1" + word);
```

Example:

```
String.prototype.sreplace = function(start, length, word) {
    return this.replace(
        new RegExp("^(.{" + start + "}).{" + length + "}"),
        "$1" + word);
};

"This is a test string".sreplace(10, 4, "replacement");
// "This is a replacement string"
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/9zP7D/

Comment: This is how I would do it personally. ♥ regex.

Answer (score 0):

The [Underscore String library](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string) has a splice method which works exactly as you specified.

```
_("This is a test string").splice(10, 4, 'replacement');
=> "This is a replacement string"
```

There are a lot of other useful functions in the library as well. It clocks in at 8kb and is available on [cdnjs](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.string/2.3.0/underscore.string.min.js).

Comment: @cr0nicz I was referring to Underscore.string. Check the link.